# Elastic Search - Lookup Nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I am going through the documentation of network settings - I had few queries with respect to the best practices .

1. Should the nodes be assigned static ip address for other nodes to reach out reliably or
2. DNS lookup
3. Doesn't matter the nodes going up or down

What should be the best practise

Comment: It depends on what kind of problem you want to solve. For example: do you want to upscale or downscale your ES server in the future?

Comment: Not sure if the question doesnt sound simple, what are the "mostly used" best practices used to look up the nodes irrespective of scaling up or down

Comment: again "depends" is always boring answer :-)

Comment: The only best practice and recommendation around network settings in elasticsearch is to never expose an unprotected node to the public internet, besides that you just needs to make sure that your nodes can talk to each other, it doesn't matter if you are using static ip addresses or hostnames. Using IPs or hostnames is something that really depends on how your structure is configured.